# Show a thumbnail for a URL embedded in a Google Blogger blog post

Tags: url, blogger

Writing a blog post, in Google Blogger, about "Kerbal Space Program".

I want to embed the https://www.kerbalspaceprogram.com URL in my post and want Blogger to fetch a thumbnail for it.

So that when I publish it, readers will see that thumbnail and the URL   for  "Kerbal Space Program" in my post.

Something like this -
[image: Thumbnail]

Answer (score 0):

It's called "OpenGraph", take a look here: https://ahrefs.com/blog/open-graph-meta-tags/

Perhaps it could be possible if you place the OpenGraph tags directly within your blog post.

Comment: AFAIU "OpenGraph" is used in a given webpage so for that Page URL a thumbnail can be fetched by other services. What I want (or wonder if possible) 
is to make Google Blogger fetch a thumbnail for an arbitrary URL of Page, that uses "OpenGraph", that I'm referencing in my blog post.